# Week Number with Get-Date

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell command:

```
Get-Date -UFormat %V
```

On Monday it shows bad week number and I don't know why. How do I add one to get the correct week number? I set everywhere that first day of week is Monday but didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Is your locale set to use the Gregorian calendar? Please add the outcome of `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture | fl *` to your question. Also check if the calendar uses the `FirstFourDayWeek` to be week 1. You can do this with `([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule`

Answer (score 3):

Try using this method to get the week number of the year. [Found here](https://gist.github.com/dstreefkerk/c6efb053b27fdc10155a)

```
function Get-WeekNumber([datetime]$DateTime = (Get-Date)) {
    $cultureInfo = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture
    $cultureInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($DateTime,$cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,$cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
}

Get-WeekNumber  # -> 7, for instance
```

Comment: I changed my PC date to 17.02.2020 and this date is in week number 8, but in powershell I still get number 7. Understand me?

Comment: His code works for me, try calling the function with Get-WeekNumber("2020-02-17")

Comment: I got this: PS C:\Users\skryj> Get-WeekNumber("2020-02-17")
7

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is the ISO8601 weeknumber, where

- a week starts at Monday
- week 1 is the first week that contains a Thursday

To get this weeknumber, you can use the function below:

```
function Get-Iso8601WeekNumber([datetime]$DateTime = (Get-Date)) {
    # ISO8601: Week starts on Monday and Week 1 is the week that contains Thursday
    $calendar = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Calendar
    $dow      = $calendar.GetDayOfWeek($DateTime)
    if ($dow -ge [DayOfWeek]::Monday -and $dow -le [DayOfWeek]::Wednesday) {
        $DateTime = $DateTime.AddDays(3)
    }
    return $calendar.GetWeekOfYear($DateTime, [Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday)
}
```

Using your example

```
Get-Iso8601WeekNumber "2020-02-17"
```

returns `8`

<sup>Note the use of `InvariantCulture` as opposed to `CurrentCulture`</sup>